# How to determine which control opens ContextMenuStrip

Tags: vb.net

In my form I have MenuStrip, ContextMenuStrip and DataGridView.
This same ContextMenuStrip is attachetd to one MenuStripItem as "DropDown" and to DataGridView as "ContextMenuStrip". That works good.

Problem is that I have to know what is opening that ContextMenuStrip (MeuStripItem or DataGridView) so I can hide some Items depending on that.

This is my approach where I try to determine if caller is MenuStrip1 which don't work.

```
   Private Sub mycontextmenu_Opening(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles mycontextmenu.Opening

       If CType(sender, MenuStrip) Is MenuStrip1 Then
          ExitToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
       Else
          ExitToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
       End If
   End Sub
```

Here error message appears: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip'.
Please help to solve described problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sender is going to be the context menu strip
the source control property will retrieve the owner instance

```
Private Sub mycontextmenu_Opening(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles mycontextmenu.Opening

   If mycontextmenu.SourceControl is MenuStrip1 Then
      ExitToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
   Else
      ExitToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
   End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Tim and thanks. That works. But why this don't work?        If mycontextmenu.SourceControl Is MenuStrip1 Then
            '' something
        ElseIf mycontextmenu.SourceControl Is DataGridView Then
            '' something else
        End If   It says: DataGridView is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: The seconded item in question: ElseIf mycontextmenu.SourceControl Is DataGridView Then

Data grid view IS A type. You need tot declare an instance of the class in order to use it.

Dim dgv as new datagridview